# Azure Pipeline - Selenium automation - Chrome Headless Browser - Unable to Set window size as 1920, 1200

Tags: azure, selenium, azure-pipelines, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to set browser size 1920X1200 and unable to go beyond 1036X780. tried with 1920* 1080 as well.

Below

```
    ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    option.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
    option.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    option.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    option.addArguments("--headless");
    option.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1200");
    String chromeDriver=Settings.getInstance().getDriverEXEDir()+"chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver);
    wDriver = new ChromeDriver(option);
    System.out.println(((RemoteWebDriver) wDriver).getCapabilities().getVersion());
    System.out.println(wDriver.manage().window().getSize());
    wDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    wDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1200));
    System.out.println(wDriver.manage().window().getSize());
    return wDriver;
```

Results :

```
90.0.4430.85  --> Chrome Version 
(1004, 748)  --> with start maximized and set window size as 1920*1200
(1036, 780)  --> with manage window maximize and set size through dimension
```

Comment: What about this issue, does the answer will help you? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;

public class BrowserOperations {
    WebDriver driver;

    //this will open browser with default size
    public void launchBrowser() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    public void resizeBrowser() {
        Dimension d = new Dimension(800,480);
        //Resize current window to the set dimension
        driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Libin.. given suggestion is not working.. I've same approach in the above code and it didn't help.. I've problem in Azure pipeline whereas in local it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to use this extension: [Screen Resolution Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-autotest.screen-resolution-utility-task) in your pipeline instead of using the wDriver.manage()

This might be a work around.